# Is it possible to put "have" instead of "had" inside this sentence?

Tags: past-perfect

**The seminar instructor provided so much repetitive information that attendees felt they had not learned much from her session.**

I think I can put **"have"** where **"had"** comes inside the sentence.

Can I?

Comment: What do you think the difference is?  Or do you think it would make no difference in the meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot directly replace **had** with **have** without also changing the tense of **feel**.
It should be either

> ... attendees **felt** they **had** not learned ...
> or
> ... attendees **feel** they **have** not learned ...